# How to set the screen resolution in pythoncard

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.7, pythoncard

I want to set the resolution of my application as per the resolution of the system screen its running on. i want to be on top and also in full screen covering even the taskbar as i am using windows. i want the app to open like the ATM interface, so the app should fill the entire screen. 
please help me to find the solution.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame object has a "ShowFullScreen" method that you could use. I just tested it and it works alright, although it doesn't show the title bar of the app. I don't know if you care about that though.

EDIT: Uh, to call a method on the frame object, you would do something like

```
self.ShowFullScreen(True)
```

or

```
myFrame.ShowFullScreen(True)
```

Comment: can u please explain me how to achieve it, i am new to python and pythocard. i don't mind the title bar, i just want to achieve it in full screen, like in an ATM Interface. Please do help. thank u so much for replying.